# I still have this issue: C++ get Partition Styles

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to C / C ++. This is an exercise. And I don't really understand it. The code above is that I copied on internet.

I'm learning C ++, so even though the code is C, I want to switch back to C ++.

I need to understand the code and output the screen:

- is MBR disk/drive
- is GPT disk/drive
- or is RAW disk/drive

I am having trouble retrieving information about the Hard Drive Partition Types in C/C++.

I pressed F5 on Visual Studio 2013, and was notified:

The variable 'partitions_style' is being used without being initialized.

I still have another problem: I use the **clean** command in **DiskPart** for My Hard Drive. When I ran the test, I found IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX did not recognize PartitionStyle RAW correctly, because this time my hard drive was RAW DISK (and certainly not PartitionStyle MBR or PartitionStyle GPT).

Please help me.
Thanks.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BOOL Get_Partition_Styles(LPWSTR wszPath, PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX p_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)
{
    DWORD partitionsSize = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)+127 * sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX);
    p_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX = (PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)malloc(partitionsSize);
    HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;                  
    DWORD junk = 0;                        
    hDevice = CreateFileW(wszPath,  
        0,                          
        FILE_SHARE_READ |           
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,                       
        OPEN_EXISTING,             
        0,                          
        NULL);                      
    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return (FALSE);
    }
    bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,     
        IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX,   
        NULL, 0,                          
        p_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX, partitionsSize,
        &junk,                         
        (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
    return (bResult);
}

void enum_Partitions()
{
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    { 
        WCHAR volume[MAX_PATH];
        wsprintf(volume, L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%d", i);
        HANDLE h = CreateFile(volume, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        bool success = h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        if (!success)
            break;
        wcout << endl << endl << endl << L"Disk #" << i << endl;

        PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX partitions_style; // disk drive geometry structure
        BOOL bResult = FALSE;             // generic results flag
        bResult = Get_Partition_Styles(volume, partitions_style);
        if (!bResult)
        {
            wcout << L"Partition Style: " << partitions_style->PartitionStyle << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            wcout << L"Get_Partition_Styles failed. Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        CloseHandle(h);
    }

    free(partitions_style);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    enum_Partitions();
    bool success_nh;
    cin >> success_nh;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: The code has a memory leak problem. Regardless of the success of `malloc`, you should put `free()` in `for{}`, because the life cycle of `partitions_style` is in `for{}`, I recommend putting `malloc` in the same `{}` as free() instead of putting it in the function. In addition, *The variable'partitions_style' is being used without being initialized.* means, you need to initialize it like `PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX partitions_style=NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

You pass a `PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX` to `Get_Partition_Styles()` but in the function you say `p_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX = (PDRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX)malloc(partitionsSize);` so you have just overridden the value you passed in.

Since you are passing by value, the updated version is not visible in the caller and so the one in the caller is never set to a value. (also the one in the called function is probably a memory leak since there is a malloc but no free).

As a side note: C or C++ ?

If you're in C++ you could pass a reference but then why are you using malloc ?

If your're in C then you could pass a pointer to be populated (the old version of passing a reference :-)